# How to pass a variable to an Action from an intercepted request in PlayFramework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am intercepting all the requests to my play application by overriding onRouteRequest method of GlobalSettings. Now, I need to send some data to the despatched action from here so that I dont perform all those calculations in all the actions.  How do I set an attribute to the request (play.api.mvc.RequestHeader) object that I pass to the super onRouteRequest method ?

Comment: Setting an attribute is not available because in functional, we're in an immutable environment. So that, when adding stuff to the session for instance, you create "a new one" with  `withSession`. And in the context of onRouteRequest you cannot create a new request because you won't be able to give this new to your underlying action

Comment: +100, same boat, have a data snippet to inject into the Request that applies to ALL routes/action-types. I'd like to do the data calculation in one place, onRouteRequest, and then anywhere in the application where an implicit request is in scope, have access to the data (vs. re-f-ing calc'ing it in various places or adding boilerplate for every Action to handle it).

Comment: @andypetrella scala is not purely functional. We can inject data into the Request via Action composition and WrappedRequest, effectively modifying the Request post-route. I would dearly love a placeholder Map[String,String] to set in onRouteRequest. You can copy the request and, for example give a value to the "tags" Map on the RequestHeader. Play of course, blows away your precious data, using the tags Map for routing results (controller method, type GET, etc.)

Comment: @virtualeyes you're right Scala is not purely f°. However the kernel of Play is using at most the functional paradigms in order to have concurrency easy and so on. That's why things like that are immutable in Play. However, I don't get your point? What would you like to have? In-place modification?

Comment: WrappedRequest is the only way, afaik, to simulate inject data into the Request. It works, and works quite well, just had to refactor my Authenticate action to extend a new Task action trait that maps a case class with desired params to WrappedRequest. Then, anywhere in the app, rather than referring to play.api.mvc.Request, you refer to com.company.Task, which contains user session id, and data extracted/transformed from the URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your need I don't thing using the `onRouteRequest` will work (elegantly at least).

But let's try to use a dedicated structure to intercept.

Here is how you could intercept the request, compute some generic stuff and pass it to Action

First of all, here is an `Interceptor` object that has a method `intercept` and a convenient method `username` :

```
object Interceptor {

  def intercept[A, B](f: RequestHeader => Option[B], e: RequestHeader => Result)(action: B => Action[A]): Action[(Action[A], A)] = {

    val bodyParser = BodyParser {
      request =>
        f(request) map {
          b =>
            val innerAction = action(b)
            innerAction.parser(request).mapDone {
              body => body.right.map(innerBody => (innerAction, innerBody))
            }
        } getOrElse {
          Done(Left(e(request)), Input.Empty)
        }
    }

    Action(bodyParser) {
      request =>
        val (innerAction, innerBody) = request.body
        innerAction(request.map(_ => innerBody))
    }
  }

  def username[A](check: RequestHeader => Option[String]): ((String) => Action[A]) => Action[(Action[A], A)] = intercept(check, r => Results.Unauthorized("not logged in"))

}
```

As you can see, the worker function `intercept` gives you the opportunity to compute some stuff based on the request content. Which computation result of type `B` might failed (`Option`), in that case a handler is there to tell what to do.

Having define what to compute, you can define your `action` using a function that takes a `B` and gives an `Action[A]`.

The `username` method is just a simple predefined interceptor that can enables us to define how to retrieve the logged in username, just to illustrate.

Now here is how we can use both of them in your `Controller`

```
  //index is defined for both GET and POST in routes, but fails on POST
  //  thanks to the interceptor that checks at first the used method
  //  the case mustn't be handled in the Action definition
  def index = Interceptor.intercept(
    /*check the method*/
    request => if (request.method == "GET") Some(request.method) else None,

    /*not a GET => bad request*/
    request => BadRequest(request.method + " not allowed")

  ) { /*the computation result*/method => Action {
      Ok("The method : " + method)
    }
  }

  //this controller retrieve the username in the session and renders it in a OK response
  def secured = Interceptor.username(r => r.session.get("username")) { username => Action {
      Ok("You're logged in as " + username)
    }
  }

  //this enables you to logged in => store in session
  def login(u:String) = Action { request => {
      Ok("Logged in as " + u) withSession(("username" -> u))
    }
  }
```

Now if you have a generic computation you can create your preconfigured interceptor (here I'm using a case class but simply defining a function that partially applies the `interceptor` is enough)

```
  case class Intercept[B] (f: RequestHeader => Option[B], e: RequestHeader => Result) {

    def apply[A](action: B => Action[A]) = Interceptor.intercept[A,B](f, e)(action)

  }


  val getInterceptor = Intercept[String](
    request => if (request.method == "GET") Some(request.method) else None,
    request => BadRequest(request.method + " not allowed")
  )


  def index2 = getInterceptor { method => Action {
      Ok("Da method : " + method)
    }
  }
```

**EDIT** related to the comment:

Accordingly to your comment, here is how you could do using an interceptor (note that I've mocked up the host retrieval and checking)

Using `hosted` and `anotherHosted`, you'll be able to test this workflow:

- /hosted/false?host=myhost => 404 because at first myhost is not cached and I provided false to the checked mockup
- /hosted/true?host=myhost => not in cache but it will add it, and then no 404
- /hosted/anotherHosted/false?host=myhost => in cache because it is hosted => no 404
- /hosted/anotherHosted/false?host=notMyhost => 404

Here is the code

```
def getHost(request:RequestHeader) = request.queryString.get("host").get.head
def checkHost(host:String, b: Boolean) = b

val checkHosted = (b: Boolean) => Intercept[String](
  request => {
    val host = getHost(request)
    Cache.getAs[String](host) match {
      case x@Some(_) => x
      case None => if (checkHost(host, b)) {
        Cache.set(host, host)
        Some(host)
      } else None
    }

  },
  request => NotFound(getHost(request) + "not hosted")
)

def hosted(b:String) = checkHosted(b.toBoolean) {
  host => Action {
    Ok("this host is ok : " + host)
  }
}
def anotherHosted(b:String) = checkHosted(b.toBoolean) {
  host => Action {
    Ok("this host is ok : " + host)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, Let me tell you the exact scenario, I am building a hosted application which users can signup for and map their domain to. When their users/customers hit their mapped domain, it first checks if the domain is hosted by us or else return a 404 error. If the domain is hosted, I want to pass on the site information to all the actions, so that I dont fetch it again in them.